# Ввод элементов массива и сумма элементов до максимального

Tags: c, массивы

Есть массив, который мы вводим с клавиатуры. Необходимо определить из этих элементов максимальный (например, массив [1 33 24 -4 36 9], максимальный эл-т это [36]) и посчитать сумму элементов до него.

Я сделал счёт суммы всех элементов больше нуля, но больше не знаю :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {
    int a[20], n, i, s;
    s = 0;
    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    a[0] = 0;
    printf("Insert array's size (less than or equal 20, more than 0): ", n);
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    while (n > 20 || n <= 0) {
        printf("Size should be less than 20!\n");
        printf("Insert array's size (less than or equal 20, more than 0): ", n);
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
    }
    while (i <= n-1) {
        printf("Insert %d element: ", i+1);
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i+1]);
        i++;
        if (a[i] > 0) {
        s = s + a[i];
    }
    }
    printf("\nSum of elements, which > 0 = %d\n", s);
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: В написанном вами условии вроде бы речь идет о сумме вообще (а не только положительных элементов), но сути дела это не меняет. По ходу подсчета суммы `s += a[i];` ищите максимум и запоминайте текущее значение суммы.. Что-то типа -- `if (a[i] > amax) {amax = a[i]; maxsum = s;}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[SIZE];
    int max = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 20 - 10;
        //scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        printf("%4d", a[i]);
        if (max < a[i])
            max = a[i];
    }
    printf("\n");


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != max && a[i] > 0)
        {
            sum += a[i];
        }
        if (a[i] == max)break;
    }
    printf("Max - %d\nSum - %d\n", max, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]